# Question about adverbs and what they modify

Tags: adverbs, modifiers

Consider the following sentences

- *I am definitely very hungry*
- *I am definitely a hungry person*
- *I am definitely hungry*
- *I am always hungry*

I’m unsure of how to tell what these adverbs modify. Do these adverbs of certainty/frequency modify the verb “to be” or the adjective “hungry?”

Does “definitely” modify “very hungry” in the first sentence?

In the second sentence, I added a noun phrase- does that change anything?

The adverb “definitely” must modify the verb “to be”; does that mean “definitely” also modifies “to be” in the sentences with adjectives?

Is this sentence correct?

> “The definitely hungry boy get something to eat.”

Comment: You could mull over the syntactic difference (*feasibly* reflecting a semantic difference, but in practice not normally) between ***I truly am sorry*** and ***I am truly sorry***. Does that help?

Comment: What does it mean logically? Is the hunger definite, or the fact of being hungry? It's possible that either is the case. You can also use the adjectival phrase to modify an  noun and see if that makes sense: "a definitely hungry man" is a bit awkward but makes sense.

Comment: The adverbs are modifiers in the copular VP.

Comment: What @StuartF said. *I saw a definitely hungry man* doesn't mean the same as *I definitely saw a hungry man*. But that's exactly the same ***semantic and syntactic*** distinction in my ***truly sorry*** example, which doesn't involve either version being particularly unusual or awkward..

Answer (score 4):

'Always' is qualifying the copular independent clause (here, also the matrix sentence) 'I am hungry'; this is a typical adverbial usage. It adds temporal detail to the statement 'I am hungry'. It doesn't really make sense to argue that it modifies just the copula 'be'.

With the other examples, though 'definitely' is usually a 'sentence/sentential adverb' [traditional analysis] showing **modality** (speaker's comment on their assessment of the likelihood of a statement being true: 'It will definitely rain within the next few days'), here context virtually demands that it must be taken as a mere **intensifier** (virtually equivalent to an exclamation mark, or 'really' premodifying 'hungry': a modifier-of-adjective usage) (though 'definitely very' using 'definitely' as an intensifier is unacceptably redundant) or perhaps a **veridical** marker (equivalent to 'I'm not putting this on').  If modal or veridical, it gives a comment on (ie about) the whole statement of the matrix sentence. I'd class it as a *pragmatic marker* in these usages rather than overfill the adverb repository.

Comment: "I am here" is a clause, not a verb phrase. Verb phrases don't have subjects

Comment: I don't understand those upvotes. ***I am here*** is a fully-formed *sentence / statement*, not a clause or a verb phrase (statements *are* sentences, but clauses and phrases are *parts* of sentences).

Comment: @FumbleFingers "I am here" is also a clause. A clause is something that has subject an predicate.

Comment: Where does "I am here" cone from?

Comment: I'd say *The NHS will **definitely** treat anyone dying of cancer* is a "sentential adverb" usage, as would be the same text with ***definitely*** moved to the start or end of the utterance. I'm not quite sure of the status of *The NHS **definitely will** treat anyone dying of cancer*, but *The NHS will treat anyone **definitely dying** of cancer* is definitely different (where it's specifically adverbially modifying ***dying***, stressing the "truth value" of that adjectival label).

Answer (score 0):

I would understand *definitely" in "the definitely hungry boy" to be confirming that the use of the adjective "hungry" is valid. It is a kind of supplemental "meta" predication. Similarly, "I am *truly* sorry" is a self-referential remark about the sincerity of the statement.

> The boy is definitely hungry. *There's no doubt about it*.
>
> That mushroom is definitely poisonous.
> *I assure you,* that mushroom is poisonous
>
> That mushroom is probably OK to eat. *I have some good reasons to believe it is not poisonous.*

Comment: I don't understand the point of your final sentence if you're not intending to differentiate it from *I **truly am** sorry* (also a "self-referential remark about the sincerity of the statement").

Comment: Wasn't intending to differentiate it. The position of this kind of adverb doesn't change their meaning.

Comment: The point is that these adverbs modify the assertion itself, not a particular word in the assertion.

Comment: You're mistaken. There's a clear-cut *semantic* distinction between the two apologies in my comment, but *neither*  of them are true "whole sentence adverbs" (of which there are precisely *two* - with ***truly*** as the first and last word of the utterance).

Comment: The OP's question is about grammar, not semantics. In the OP's examples, the adverbs are modifiers in the copular VPs.

Comment: @BillJ: Grammar terminology isn't my specialist subject, but in the current context I don't see what use it to identify a sentence as a clause. Edwin's 'sentential adverb' suits me fine (that's what I meant by "whole sentence adverbs") - but since the OP appears to be asking ***which word does the adverb modify**?*, I still think being able to differentiate between *I **truly am** sorry* and *I **am truly** sorry* is the heart of the issue - with the unambiguously "sentential" phrasings being the two with the adverb before or after the rest of the sentence. But that's got lost here, somehow.

Comment: @BillJ: To me the answer "modifiers **in** the copular VPs" dodges OP's question. *What* does the adverb modify? I say it modifies the predication itself.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  I don't accept a semantic distinction between "I truly am sorry" and "I am truly sorry".  Unless for you "truly sorry" means "very sorry" not "sincerely sorry".

Comment: There's a clear-cut *syntactic* distinction, in that the default interpretations are that ***truly*** emphasises / confirms the truth value of the immediately-following ***verb*** in *I **truly am** sorry*, but in the alternative position *I am **truly sorry***, it's an adverbial "intensifier" for the immediately-following ***adjective*** (precisely equivalent to ***very** sorry*). Per my original comment under the question itself, those two sequences ***feasibly** reflect a semantic difference, but **in practice not normally***.

Comment: You're putting a lot of weight on word position, like a machine parser.  I've heard this: *I am [pause for effect] **truly** [pause for effect] sorry*.

Comment: The expressions "It's a modifier in the copular VP" and "It modifies the copular VP" have the same meaning. In the OP's examples, "definitely" is an adjunct in clause structure.

Comment: @BillJ: In the sentence *It is definitely broken* the word **definitely** modifies **is broken**.  It doesn't modify **broken** alone. Would you agree?

Comment: That's what I said!